# Heroku sends back HTTP status 444 for AJAX requests - why?

Tags: ajax, jquery, post, heroku, nginx

My front end web app is using jQuery's AJAX functions (`$.ajax`, `$.getJSON`, `$.post`) to call a back end data API via GET and POST requests. In the browser console and in the Heroku app's logs I can see the calls are rejected with an HTTP status of 444, which is an Nginx custom status:

> Used in Nginx logs to indicate that the server has returned no information to the client and closed the connection (useful as a deterrent for malware).

(though it doesn't necessarily mean they're running Nginx or that this is due to Nginx)

Anyone know why this would occur or how I can remedy it? The calls are nothing fancy - here's an example coffeescript:

```
jQuery ($) ->

  tbody = $("table#top_five_table > tbody")

  $.ajaxSetup(
    dataType: "json"
  )

  $.getJSON url, (data, status, xhr) => [
    tbody.empty().html( data_munging(data) )
  ]
```

Everything works locally, but obviously I'm not running it with an Nginx proxy (as I assume Heroku are). The request headers locally and on the Heroku instance appear identical.

Any help or insight will be much appreciated.

Comment: Probably a good question to ask Heroku directly.

Comment: I just have, but I'm happy to share the wealth if anyone on here can answer.

Comment: What kind of application is the back end API ? rails ? other ?

Comment: @pjam both front end and back end are Sinatra. I've attempted making calls via curl to the backend (`curl -H "Accept: application/json" -X GET "MY_HIGHLY_SECRET_URL" ;) and they are also unsuccessful, with the same 444 in the logs.

Comment: Ok, I just tried a curl request to one of the remaining non-JSON routes on the backend and it also got a 444, so this is not just jQuery (and yes, I know, I should've tried that first... :/ )

Comment: I've given the answer, unhelpful as it is to anyone else other than a warning. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shame of it - I found some code that checks for the referrer and will take certain actions to allow/deny routes depending on that, and localhost is bypassed hence it always working. So it's a bug.

Because I've offered a bounty I don't seem to be able to close the question so I'm answering it. Thanks to all who spent any time looking into this.